# Error while installing bcryptjs using NPM

Tags: npm, ssl-certificate, cpanel, npm-install, bcrypt

I am trying to install a npm app on cpanel. I have already moved all my files on the server. All my libraries gets installed without any problems other than bcryptjs. I get the following error log when I try to install it:

```
97 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/bcryptjs failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
97 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/opt/alt/alt-nodejs18/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
97 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
97 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)
97 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
97 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
97 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
97 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

I have read online about installing ca certificates but I already have SSL certificates installed for my domain. Please any help would be appreciated.